# Best architectural choices to use ContentProviders, IntentServices and Loaders

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I working on an Android project in which I need to fetch JSON data from a remote server, update a SQLite Db with the retrieved data and update a listview.

I am using IntentServices to fetch data (I do not need regular updates) while the DB is wrapped by a ContentProvider and thus accessed by ContentResolvers.

Now I need to update the views. To this end I think I should rely on loaders but I am wondering about what would be the best architectural choice.

I would make the Activity/Fragment hosting the listView a ContentObserver and register it to the ContentProvider AND, when data is changeged (onChange method), start a Loader aimedt a querying the data and updating the view.

This would work for updates to the DB but when the application is started. I therefore need to explicitly start a Loader in the onCreate method of the Activity/Fragment.

Am i Right?

Comment: have you seen AsyncQueryHandler?

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally like this approach, as working directly with the database and relying on dataset observers usually means you won't build a proper model, and, in my opinion, you will be lacking a very important abstraction layer in your application.

Sure it works great and can be implemented extremely easily and very fast in simple apps meant at displaying information only and nothing more, but what if you want to change the apps behaviour and expand the app in the future?

I have found that the most expandable and solid way of linking database data to the views is through the use of proper data models and a solid observer pattern that links the data manipulation of the controller to the registered views.

Answer (score 0):

in briefly i think best way to communication UI (acitivty/fragments ) with other parts of your apps (like network services ) is to  use event base libraries . [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)  v [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) are best event base library for android.

for more information below link is very useful :

[Durable Android REST Clients](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2014/04/07/durable-android-rest-clients.html)

notice : but if you want use loaders, you can  read source of SeriesGuide app that use loaders for communication UI and Services

source code : [SeriesGuide](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide/blob/master/SeriesGuide/src/main/java/com/battlelancer/seriesguide/ui/MoviesSearchFragment.java)

hope this answer helps you ;)